Maximum subgroup within a set
Suppose we have a set $S\subseteq \{ 0,1 \}^{2n}$ satisfying $|S|\geq 2^n$ (promised $ 0^n\in S$), then what is the largest $S'\subseteq S$ such that $S'$ is a group? There is a lot of literature on largest subgroups of $S$ which are sum-free (i.e., for every $x,y\in S$, $x+y\notin S$), but my question is about the converse.

Surely it could be that no such $S'$ exists for $S$ of size up to $2^{2n}-1$: just avoid $(0,\ldots,0)$.

So presumably you should require that $S$ include the zero vector, to ensure some subsets that are groups exist.

Thanks, addressed your comment!

It depends on $S$. I don't understand what you are asking. Are you looking for an efficient algorithm to compute a largest subgroup within $S$?

If the question is about an algorithm, then a trivial one is to pick all possible basis $B\subseteq S$ where $|B| < 2n$ and use it to find whether all elements produced by that basis exist in $S$. Time complexity of this algorithm is $$T(|S|) = \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}O\left(|S|^{i} \:\cdot\: 2^i\right) = O\left(\left( 2\cdot|S| \right)^{2n-1} \right)$$
We can also use early stopping here, so if the largest group size is $|S'| = 2^k$
$$T(|S|, k) = O\left(\left( 2\cdot|S| \right)^{min(2n-1, k+1)} \right)$$

If we are talking about bounds on any arbitrary $S \subseteq \{0,1\}^{2n}$, they are given as follows: if the size of the largest group within $S$ is $|S'| = 2^k$, then
$$ 2^k \leq |S| \leq (2^k-1)\cdot 2^{2n-k} + 1$$
I'll explain these now: the lower bound of $2^k$ is trivial to understand. For the upperbound,

I will first prove that if $ |S| > (2^t-1)\cdot 2^{2n-t} + 1$ for some $t\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, then $k>t$
The next step is to show that this is the best possible upper bound, by constructing a $S$ with $|S| = (2^k-1)\cdot 2^{2n-k} + 1$

First point
Let a $S$ exist with the group $S' \subseteq S$ with size $|S'|=2^k$. We can label the elements in $S'$ as $a_1, a_2, \dots a_{2^k}$ where $a_1= 0^{2n}$. Now, for any element $b\in S$ where $b\not\in S'$, at least one of $\{b + a_2, b + a_3, \dots , b + a_{2^k}\}$ must not be in $S$, otherwise we can take the subset $S''$ combining $S'$ and $b+ S'$ which is a group with size $2^{k+1}$.
From the above, we can reach at the inequality $$\begin{split}
\frac{|S| - 2^k}{2^k-1} &\leq |\{0,1\}^{2n}| - |S| \\
|S| - 2^k &\leq (2^k-1)\cdot 2^{2n} - (2^k-1)\cdot |S| \\
2^k\cdot |S| &\leq (2^k-1)\cdot 2^{2n} + 2^k \\
|S| &\leq (2^k-1)\cdot 2^{2n-k} + 1
\end{split}$$
Second point
Construct $$S = \left(\{0,1\}^{2n} - \{0,1\}^{2n-k} \cdot 0^k \right) \cup \{0^{2n}\}$$
This has a subset $S' = 0^{2n-k} \cdot \{0,1\}^k$ which is a group with size $2^k$. Also $S$ can not have any group with greater size because any group $S'' \subseteq S$ cannot have any two elements which have the same last $k$ bits.
